# How to count after 30 minute start from 07:00 using PHP?

Tags: php

I needed a count of times, start at 07:00 (morning)

just like these :

```
07:00 - 07:30 => H1
07:31 - 08:00 => H2
08:01 - 08:30 => H3

until H48
```

How i can do this on code PHP???

Comment: you need what time is it after H48. Do I understand it right?

Comment: What  have you done so far? Could you also put your code. And also is this military time?

Comment: @JayJoshi : no i mean after that on H48 it will reset back again to H1.

Comment: [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) is not a free code writing service. You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [doing more research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592) if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) a good question.

Comment: Do you want the time in your own time frame.? Or any system's.? Or user's time frame?

Comment: Did my answer help.? I guess it gives the result like you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get time by using `date('format',time())`. You can use it to get current time in hour and minutes and do little mathematical conversion to get it in format of H1-48.

#### Code

```
date_default_timezone_set("UTC"); 

$time =  date('H',time());   // hours in 48 hours format
$time = $time - 7;    // because it starts from 7 AM
$time = 2*$time;      // because there are 2 parts in each hour

if(date('i',time()) > 30)
{
  $time++;
}

$time++; // to get in range of 1 to 48

echo "H".$time;
```

note: this will give the output based on UTC. you can change that by giving your country string. for ex: `date_default_timezone_set("Europe/Dublin")`

get your country string from [here](http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.php).

Comment: ok i try your code. i will inform if work or not.

Comment: Owww.. Thats!!! U hero!!! Thats exactly i want it!! Tq!!

Comment: I am happy that i could help :D